# double items get selected when one item is clicked in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a  custom listview with an image and textview. When I select the first item the last item also gets selected and image changes for both items. I couldn't find what is the problem. pls help..

Here is the code for it.

**EDIT**

```
lv5=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView05);
lv5.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.productselecttext,R.id.pstext,arr));     
lv5.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){ 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {   
if(lv5.getItemAtPosition(position) != null)
    { ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.oi); icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.v); } } });
```

Comment: could you attach your customListView here?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code here. So that we can find the issue..

Comment: lv5=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView05);
    lv5.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.productselecttext,R.id.pstext,arr));
   
    

    
   lv5.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
    
    
    
    if(lv5.getItemAtPosition(position) != null){
     
       ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.oi);
       icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.v);
       
    }

   }
   
   });

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code over there. It would make  it much easier to find out what the problem is, if the code is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this in your listview.setOnClickListener method:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(view.findViewById(R.id.R.id.oi).getVisibility()==ImageView.VISIBLE){
                              ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.oi); 
                              icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.v); 
                            } } });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution!!

With full expelantion and code example, here: http://www.codegod.biz/WebAppCodeGod/Android-ListView-with-dynamic-Images-AID588.aspx

It was a long search for a solution..